# CakePHP: how to make a submit button with link, which stores the request data

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a Form in Cakephp(version 2.4.4):

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Servicegroup');?>`

I have to find a way to submit this form using a button, which contains a link. Besides I need to have all the request data from this form when I access the link. How could I implement this in the best way?
I am tryin with: 
`echo $this->Html->link($this->Form->button('calculateBudget', array('class' => 'btn btn_yellow', 'type' => 'submit')), array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'calculateBudget'), array('class' => 'lbOn', 'escape' => false));`
but this does not submit the form

Comment: use on click jQuery submit form

Comment: @Deep, could you provide a little example of how could I submit cakephp form using jquery. `jQuery( "#submit" ).click(function() {
     jQuery( "#form" ).submit();
   });` with the `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Servicegroup', array('id' => 'form'));?>` does not work.